# Did Elon Musk's Tesla Roadster actually launch to space?

Tags: spacex, nasa, materials, physics, outgassing

I'm sorry I have to ask this question but I need evidence for a friend.  My answer to her that I trust people who specialize in the field to know better than me is 'BS' to her.

So to begin...
My friend believes the earth is flat.
She believes NASA is fake.
And now she thinks the Elon Musk Falcon Heavy launch wasn't real (well maybe the launch in the Earth's atmosphere) but the car in space was completely fake.
She wants me to research and provide evidence that it was real and a car can exist in space.
I know I know, many people say it's not worth the time but this girl is a dear friend and have to see this through.  Plus if we're not trying to educate the world aren't we kind of being hypocritical? Yes? Haha ok here we go...

So the main point I'd need to have scientific evidence of is can the car exist in space.
Her points...

- a car would be destroyed in a vacuum
- elon says "you know it's real because it looks so fake"
- outgassing
- the car goes from a room into space
- did you see the photo of it from launch
- you know how much money it takes to “launch” something into space
- you think he just did that to have it “orbit for 1 billion years” that is literally so dumb it’s incomprehensible
- engineering teams never see the satellites launch ‘they just build them’
- look at the car - put the image in a photoshop editor - it’s worse than avatar special effects
- you think there are just cameras fixed to some car that’s literally just cruising around space and there’s not debris next to it from the
  rocket and there are no shots of the camera attachment from one side
  of the car to the other
- uber has 6000 engineers, they don’t know any of what uber is actually doing, they all do pieces of it, that isn’t even a valid
  argument, there’s only a portion of every business that knows
  anything, you think they send a brief to 6000 employees that they are
  going to do a launch
- next piece of evidence https://www.livescience.com/61690-why-spacex-roadster-looks-fake.html
  everyone thinks it looks fake, even elon, and his excuse is “the
  colors are more crisp in space”, and then people just believe that??
- you need to watch the footage again and wonder why there are articles upon articles explaining why “it looks fake”, when you don't
  think yourself it does
- I said I trust experts and asked who she trusts which she responded...no one, but that’s why i ask questions, to myself
  included, “do i think this looks real?” no, why?, “because of X Y and
  Z”, okay why is x this, research look, ask, repeat, always
- i expect this from you too - outgassing, photo editor images, see what has been previously launched
- look to see where the cameras are in the different angles
- instead of me asking you to research why it’s fake, you can instead tell me what you researched to show you it’s real, i will listen - i
  did this - your turn
- i don’t want any of the “trusting people” “watched it live” bull that’s not evidence, I’ll wait

[image]
[image]

- https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19690026573.pdf
- you can’t lose 1 billion a year, stock dropped 8.63% just last night, and then be spending millions to randomly launch a car into
  space. It doesn’t make sense - it’s a distraction to justify his lack
  of use with tax payer money

Have a field day ladies & gents ;) and if you could provide resources to anything that would possibly help educate and validate your answer I'd be moooore than appreciated.

## roundearth4life

Comment: If she wont believe people who watched it live then she probably already decided to not believe - belief is not about facts or evidence..

Comment: Why do you feel it important to convince her? What good does it do you to try? Remember this: people have a right to be **completely wrong** about things. It is not your duty to try to force-feed someone the truth, no matter how deluded they are. And also note this: it is not as if she has not had the evidence available to her. **The evidence does not matter to her**. She is not concerned about knowing the facts. She is concerned about being in control of her own truth. My advice to you: just conclude that she is completely wrong, and leave it at that.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelK she's a great long-time friend though and a sweetheart of a person -  It mainly stems from a family members beliefs being pushed onto her.  She's gullible and a bit naive, but as I said - maybe she doesn't see the facts.  She hears from someone she trusts - "oh yeah that thing they showed on TV, that's fake."  Elon's a fraud.  I mean if you were from a third world country and someone you trusted told you that - you'd believe them too...however if someone else you trusted provided you with convincing evidence to the contrary maybe you'd be on a path to changing your views.

Comment: I saw a couple of gifs from people with telescopes who found the second stage and roadster where it was supposed to be. Would she believe them? Would she accept if they let her take a look? Or would she just say they are tricking her? If you can guess the response you have a better estimate what yu your chances are. But I agree with MichaelK

Comment: @jkavalik thanks for the tips I mean any means of staking up  unsurmountable evidence could help.  I'll definitely take a peep and try to find those images.  While it may not change her views immediately i think it will at minimum start a period of questioning.

Comment: @pmanning I ask again: **why do you feel it important to force her to change her views**?! What does it do for her? Why are you trying? Are you doing it for her sake, or are you just trying to — entirely selfishly — scratch that itch that stems from hearing something that is completely false? Yes it is annoying, but you have to step back from the whole situation and ask yourself "**WHY** am I doing this?". What is your goal and why do you have that goal?

Comment: @pmanning "flat Earth" is a bit easier to disprove imho than the "fake roadster" thing - the "roundnes" and the size of Earth was computed by Eratosthenes. Many arguments about the latter will require understanding or math and physics which is often considered "bad" by people ignorant enough. *"you think he just did that to have it “orbit for 1 billion years” that is literally so dumb it’s incomprehensible"* - no understanding of rocket testing and PR stunts either ;)

Comment: @MichaelK valid question.  Well this is a little bet we'd say we do she said she'd take my evidence to heart and I'd listen to her.  She's someone who's employed at a major tech company and has major clout.  I do believe it is selfish of me.  However, I do believe it is a major issue in our society of letting ridiculous/cultish views be pushed onto the weak minded.  We whine about poor policy choices from the government but don't want to put in the ground work of helping educate.  That's where I see our hypocrisy.

Comment: @pmanning Well here is the thing: we have a right to **think** whatever we want. We have freedom of thought. Article 18 of the [Universal Declaration of Human Rights](http://www.un.org/en/universal-declaration-human-rights/). She has a right to be completely, utterly, totally **wrong**. She has made that choice. As an adult human being, she has the right to make it. That does not mean we have to like it, or not have opinions. But in the end, we cannot — and may not — force her to think differently. You can lead a person to the facts, but you cannot force them to think the way you want them.

Comment: @pmanning And as I said above: this is not at all about the facts to her. You are operating under the mistaken assumption that a person that has the facts **will** draw the right conclusions. This is not true for any one person of us. We all have biases that push us towards incorrect conclusions. Some just have a few more such biases. And do know that some of those biases — like a **psychiatric diagnosis** — can be quite strong... and with that such a bias can force the desire for knowing truth and understanding reality as it exists way down the priority list.

Comment: @MichaelK ok so put yourself in my position for a sec...  Someone you care about - asks you to provide evidence of how this car exists in space and these cameras can stream.  All I know is Elon Musk held a stream that rationally and consensus-wise was successful.  However if Kim Jung-Un streamed the same video yesterday you'd be skeptical no?  So basically Elon Musk is Kim Jung-Un to this girl. Shes a semi-rational ;) person and by all means functions at a high level in society.   I mean I'm just looking for some facts to present to her ... which she asked me for...  would you not do so?

Comment: @pmanning If you really want to shake up her reasoning, stop pushing against her and instead pull in her direction. Only go **much** further. "You are right... it was all fakes. In fact... **everything** is faked. I am a fake". she will go "Of course not, that is ridiculous. You are real!". "Prove it...". The point of this is to get her to reason around what she considers to be reasonable doubt and at what point we have to start trusting the evidence we have. In the end there is no solution for the problem of **Hard Solipsism**, so we have to choose when we start to trust.

Comment: @MichaelK pmanning OT: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/456687-there-is-a-cult-of-ignorance-in-the-united-states - I am not from US, but I can see it spreading even here.. They may have the right to be stupid, but wrong is *wrong* - the truth needs to be objective otherwise humanity is doomed.

Comment: @pmanning I **have** been in your situation, only much worse. The person in question was **convinced** they knew who shot Sweden's prime minister Olof Palme to death in 1986. To them, that was entirely real. They were — of course — deluded, because they were suffering from paranoid schizophrenia. No amount of facts could ever convince them because they were was entirely unable to separate deluded fantasy from reality. I am not talking about not just wanting to see truth, I mean entirely not able to do it. If your friend is suffering from a form of that, you are fighting a hopeless battle.

Comment: Great quote @jkavalik thanks! it's absolutely true - I'm from the NYC area and you only hear about it and don't really understand it's vastness.  I recently visited this friends family in Florida and this is when these views came out.  And it wasn't just 1 member.  It was even the friends and community that the family interacted with.  When you see it and experience it firsthand it brings a new reality to the situation.  It's beyond scary.

Comment: @jkavalik If that was the case we would be fighting a fierce battle against all forms of religious belief, because there is nothing objective about that. I as a militant atheist/anti-theist am **entirely opposed to that** because — as I mentioned above — we do have Freedom of Thought. The right to **think** freely trumps all. Also the quote is not relevant in this case, because the friend in question is not bringing her delusion into the public discourse nor is she demanding that people acknowledge it or join her in it.

Comment: @MichaelK as you say there is nothing objective about religious beliefs so there is nothing which could be *wrong* there. ("anti-theist" too, I don't even consider myself an atheist, but "their God is their problem" :) ) But science strives to be as objective as possible (which is ofc far from 100% because scientists are people too) and there is the "real world" which is nothing but objective (even when our understanding of it is not) - the caveman who did not believe in Smilodon just got eaten.

Comment: @jkavalik Unless she has made the assertion that she is doing science, this does not matter. The job of science is to find the facts and present them in order to let people draw their conclusions while being as informed as they can. The job of science is not to take pre-made conclusions and shove them down peoples throats, saying "Think right, **OR ELSE**!!!"... that is the prerogative of religion.

Comment: @MichaelK sure, but as she has the right to "be wrong", he has the right to tell her he thinks she is wrong. It is not "she is wrong but it is her right so better not ever touch the subject again". It may be because the friendship might end quite quickly, but not because her ignorance should be somehow protected.

Comment: Try the Interpersonal Skills stack exchange

Comment: @MichaelK yes again - this girl has not been presented with ANY facts.  Just a TV show in her mind.  Naturally, if I just argue with her I will have a bias in my presentation, but she has asked to see facts - and that's what I'm looking to give her - not to present my subjective views but present to her objective facts of science.  Then she can do with it as she pleases. No force feeding ;)

Comment: @jkavalik I am not saying her ignorance is protected. I am not saying she has no right to not be opposed. What I am saying is that OP needs to think carefully: why is he opposing? What is he trying to gain by it? What is the **goal** of opposing? The advancement of truth is in itself a laudable goal. But it is not the only one.

Comment: @pmanning I agree with JCRM here: IPS SE is the place to go. And as I said: you have to abandon the notion that the desire to know truth is the only, or even the most prevalent, driving force in people. there are other forces, and you need to be aware of them. Especially so in your close friends and — above all — in yourself.

Comment: @MichaelK I see, agreed :) should we ask to get moved to chat or will we just clean this OT?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic; this should be moved to Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange

Comment: @jkavalik as suggested I rephrased the question and added some of the stuff we talked about here and put it on IPS https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/10377/how-to-respond-to-a-flat-earther ...only to be downvoted and put on hold.  really feeling put down with people's reactions.  found a great TED talk I think we collectively need to pay more attention to - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqUaEJLfrLo&index=1&list=LLCTVeqZ7RgQSMFWKJf_CqlA

Comment: No it was a conspirsacy

Answer (score 13):

Well, if you're trying to convince her that the launch was real and a car can exist in space... I'm afraid from what I read here, you will first have to convince her that textbook physics is real.

If she believes in a flat earth, THAT is already the first problem - a flat earth does not fit with physics as we know it. So she must be convinced that either math or physics are faked by whatever world conspiracy she believes in. Gravity would pull a flat earth into a sphere, much like we have it now - so gravity is fake? ...

If you are serious about this bet, and she is a rational being (and not deluded or otherwise crazy) and CAN be convinced, your first step will need to be to find out WHAT set of alternate physics/math she believes in, and then to go and disprove them / prove that mainstream physics/math work better.

If she's not willing to list her explanations for why things fall to the ground if gravity doesn't work as mainstream physics says it does (which she cannot believe, because otherwise a flat earth would pull itself into a sphere...), why it's day and night at different times in different locations (which obviously cannot be from the earth rotating if the earth isn't roughly spherical) and so on... I'm afraid you're out of luck.

One simple and primitive way to attempt to shake up her worldview enough to MAYBE make her willing to consider that the earth is round (and maybe, maybe the other mainstream physics are real too) would be to take her and some binoculars to a harbor, preferrably one where sailing ships still dock if you can manage to find one near to you (some militaries have sailing ships as training vessels still). You can have her watch the ships arrive over the horizon, with the top parts of the ships coming into view before the rest (which is to be expected if the earth is round, but hard to explain with a flat earth). That's evidence that the flat-earth theories are wrong that she can see with her own eyes, and if she IS willing to think about her views rather than take them as fact and refuse all evidence to the opposite, that might be a first step.

I wish you good luck, but I'm afraid most flat earthers have a firm, dogmatic view on this and are unwilling to think rationally about it. So be prepared to have all evidence you dig up tossed out of the window as "they faked it" or "I'm no scientist, but I bet if they weren't all in the conspiracy they could give you the REAL explanation!" - there's no way to win with those people, and if she belongs to that category you'll have to step back and, since it sounds like she's important to you, "agree to disagree" no matter how wrong she is. Try not to grind your teeth too much, it's not healthy ;)

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't give advice on how to tackle this - the [Interpersonal Skills StackExchange](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) might be able to help you. however, rather than leave no response to the question, and have the theorists say "see, there is no answer to it" I'll briefly address the points.

1. no it wouldn't
2. exactly
3. would do what? over what time period?
4. a fairing, yes.
5. your point?
6. your point?
7. no, he did it to demonstrate the capabilities of the vehicle, including the 6 hour coast capability for some juicy government contracts. he could have done it with concrete, but look how much publicity this got him - do you know how many Tesla's that man has.
8. car builders don't see their cars loaded onto ferries and sent to other countries.
9. see #2 - what would you expect to see?
10. you can clearly see the front camera mount from the over the shoulder camera.
11. your point?
12. see #9
13. see #9
14. whatever
15. is that a question?
16. the camera mountings are shown in pictures taken before launch
17. not interested
18. I can't prove putting my head in a gas oven wont kill me, but I'm going to trust the experts and reports and not do it.
19. b. good job it's made of painted sheet metal, not a metal film. But yeah, the car electronics are probably going to be dodgy after a while.
20. Absolutely, it will be subject to those effects. Doing the maths, how much metal would have evaporated already?
21. see #7

Comment: hahaha #18 for the win

Comment: @pmanning JCRM has a point here: the "arguments" — so called — are mostly incoherent rambling. And — as uncomfortable as I am saying it — I must say that incoherent rambling of this sort is **exactly** the kind I see from delusional people when they try to argue for chemtrails, New World Order, 9/11 was an inside job... that sort of thing. The arguments are not following a chain of reasoning... there is no train of thought... it is just a jumbled **mess**. So I say again: think twice... you may be fighting an impossible battle. Do **not** assume that correct facts leads to acceptance of truth.

Comment: What's that phrase ah yes : "never argue with a fool, people may not be able to tell the difference"...